# Append average ping of IP addresses to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, ping

I have a csv file with lots of IP addresses, e.g.

```
216.156.156.26 
192.225.161.138 
...
182.16.169.129
```

I want to **ping each IP** address and **append the average time** to the csv file.
E.g.

```
216.156.156.26, 134 
192.225.161.138, 95 
...
182.16.169.129, 83
```

So far I have the following code which will read the IPs from the csv file and ping them:

```
import os
import csv

with open('ip_ping.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for line in reader:
    for ip in line:
      response = os.system('ping ' + str(ip))
      if response == 0:
        print (ip, ' is up')
      else:
        print (ip, ' is down')
```

It gives me the following output:

```
Pinging 216.156.156.26 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.156.156.26: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=54
Reply from 216.156.156.26: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=54
Reply from 216.156.156.26: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=54
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 23.229.39.34:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 23.229.39.34:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
23.229.39.34  is down
23.229.39.34  is down
Pinging 45.72.45.144 with 32 bytes of data:
Pinging 45.72.45.144 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.156.156.26: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 216.156.156.26:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 95ms, Maximum = 131ms, Average = 105ms
216.156.156.26  is up
... 
and so on
```

Any help on how to best do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Kindly have a look at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output for capturing the output of system commands, using which you could find the average ping time.

Comment: Instead of using `os.system` use `response = subprocess.run("ping google.com -n 1", capture_output=True)`. You can still use `response.returncode` when checking if the service was up, but now you will also have `response.stdout` which will give you the output of the ping command as a string. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html